# Illogical GTK theme behaviour on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I'm using X-Arc-White GTK theme in my freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. I looks really amazing, but there's a problem with GNOME own applications, like system monitor or calculator. They are shown only with default Adwaita theme.

[image]

[image]

The only themes which work for all programs are Ambiance and Radiance. Is there a reason for that behaviour?

Comment: Hey Meiden. How did you install the theme? Where are the theme files stored?

Comment: Hi. At the first, I've got the themes stored in ~/.themes, then I moved them into /usr/share/themes but the problem persist. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems those are applications installed as [snap packages](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro). You may verify it by running

```
snap list
```

The snap execution environment doesn't *see* any of the themes on your system (local or system-wide). So this is somewhat an expected behaviour.

As a workaround you may remove those snap applications by running

```
snap remove <package-name>
```

and install their apt versions by running

```
sudo apt install <package-name>
```

Comment: Whoa I'm very surprised. So Canonical is introducing snap applications as default in Ubuntu? I didn't install any of those snap packages but your suggestion was totally right. Thank you very much.